# Find a gibberish text within body using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find a gibberish text that appears in the body without any HTML tags wrapping it. The source of this text is unknown. Not sure which approach would be better to find and remove it of the page Javascript

example:

```
<body>
    <div>section</div>
    Qui3Er3^6k

</body>
```

I am trying to find the string **`Qui3Er3^6k`** using javascript and remove it off the dom.

Note: I am not using jQuery, would like to achieve it with Javascript

Comment: Ha, its just a random string appearing out of nowhere, the text remains the same when refreshed, so it should be a static text

Comment: You can make use of Regex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions Cheatsheet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet if the gibberish text is random.

Comment: @Spectric It's the literal string `"Qui3Er3^6k"` that OP wants to find. It's always the same string.

Comment: Instead of using javascript, I advise you to find the reason for this strange set of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to remove `Qui3Er3^6k` from the DOM, you can use [`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replaceAll("Qui3Er3^6k", "");
```

```html
<body>
  <div>section</div>
  Qui3Er3^6k
</body>
```

Comment: Great answer, worked charmingly well